# DataFormatString for percent with decimals only when needed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, formatting, string-formatting

I am trying to use these on EF code first properties with MVC:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Specifically:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="##.##%")]
public double? PercentOfSomething {get;set;}
```

**How do I get .2345 to display as 23.45% and .2 to display as 20%** 
In other words, only show the decimal, up to two places, if there is one.

As it is now, it just displays the format string "##.##%".  I am guessing maybe these types of format strings are not supported by the DisplayFormat attribute.

Comment: Maybe you can use default formatting and override `ToString` according to your needs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you should use "{0:##.##%}" instead of just ##.##%

Comment: Yep, just figured that out.  One of those fighting with it for a long time and then figuring it out 30 seconds after I post.

Answer (score 0):

You should put % outside {}

```
DataFormatString = "{0:0.##}%"
```